# Illegal Start of Expression : declaring a method inside another method

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I know this will probably be an easy fix, but i'm just starting out in java. I need to declare a method inside the main method that clears the screen. Line 5 is giving me an error called Illegal start of expression.

```
public class Project2
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    public static void clearScreen()
    {
    System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    }// end clearScreen()

System.out.print("\nDid it work?");
}
}
```

Comment: `I need to declare a method inside the main method that clears the screen` Good luck with that. But this Java version is not coming yet... Or is it OK in JDK8 with lambdas?

Comment: I suspect that you need to call this method inside your main() method

Answer (score 1):

Nested methods is not allowed in Java(as of yet). The closest you can get is

```
class Project2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        class InnerClass {
           void clearScreen() {
               // Do something.
           }
         }
         new InnerClass().clearScreen(); // Call it this way.
     }
 }
```

If the above solution doesn't suit, then just move that method outside your `main` and call it.

Comment: `clearScreen` should probably be static here for the OPs usecase

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a method inside a method like that.  You call methods from methods, like so:

```
public class Project2
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       clearScreen();

      System.out.print("\nDid it work?");
   }

public static void clearScreen()
{
    System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
}// end clearScreen()
}
```